# Is it possible to deploy to a Nexus Repository using Maven 1?

Tags: maven, nexus

Some of our projects still use Maven 1. Is it possible to deploy artifacts to a Nexus Maven 1 Repository using "maven:deploy" goal? I could not find the properties to set username and password.

We found a work around by sharing the storage folder of the Nexus server and deploying directly into that folder using file protocol, but this is not really a preferred solution.

Comment: First migrate those projects. As far as i know Nexus supports Maven 1 repositories...I don't know enough about Maven 1.

Comment: This is planned but no solution for the short term.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus supports hosted repositories using the Maven 1 format so you can use the usual deployment setup. Unfortunately I do NOT remember how to do the deployment with credentials in Maven 1, but I assume the archived documentation would detail that.

If you can not get this to work easily and the project is not VERY complex I would actually suggest to drop Maven 1 and upgrade to Maven 3. This would solve your problem and bring numerous improvements to your development team. Maven 1 has been unsupported and deprecated for years and which puts you into this troublesome situation.

Comment: I searched the documentation but did not found anything regarding deploying via http using Maven 1. I only found documentation for using file protocol, scp or ftp.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven 2 (not Maven 3) you can also deploy artifacts in Maven 1 format by adding "legacy to your distributionManagment

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/maven1</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
    </repository>
    ...
  </distributionManagement>
```

This won't work with Maven 3, the legacy layout support was removed in that version of Maven.

Comment: This is no solution for us as the project itself is still on Maven 1.